# Node.js environment variables undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, nodejs-server

I'm trying to use environment variables but when I use the file and run the server, I am getting only PORT variable and all of my other variables are undefined. I'm using nodemon.

**.env**

```
PORT=3000
SENDGRID_API_KEY=sometext
```

**package.json**

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node src/index.js",
    "dev": "env-cmd -f ./config/dev.env nodemon src/index.js"
  }
```

**index.js**

```
const port = process.env.PORT
const apiKey = process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY
app.listen(port, () => {  
    console.log('Server is up on port '+port)
    console.log(apiKey)
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `-f` than it wont care about the environment -e, use one of these.

`"env-cmd nodemon src/index.js"`

```
.rc file ./.env-cmdrc

{
  "development": {
    "ENV1": "Thanks",
    "ENV2": "For All"
  },
  "test": {
    "ENV1": "No Thanks",
    "ENV3": "!"
  },
  "production": {
    "ENV1": "The Fish"
  }
}
```

// Command:

`env-cmd -e production nodemon index.js`

Check:
https://github.com/toddbluhm/env-cmd

Comment: Cheers!! happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `dotenv` npm

```
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv'

dotenv.config(); 
export class Constants { 

  process.env.<YOUR_VARIABLE_NAME>

}
```